# Loop a variable function argument

Tags: php, function

Is it possible to loop a function variable from this? I am trying to loop the `$item[$a-1]`

```
echo load_func($hid, $item[$a-1]);
```

And make it something like this but I know this is wrong (just an idea):

```
echo load_func($hid, for($a=1;$a<=$addctr;$a++){$item[$a-1]});
```

This is the actual but fail because it loops the whole function.

```
echo "<select id='drpopitem-' name='drpopitem[]' size='10' multiple>";
for($a=1;$a<=$addctr;$a++){
     echo load_func($id, $item[$a-1]);
}
echo "</select>";
```

The purpose of the function is to automatically select an option based from the record saved on a table.

Comment: So why shouldn't your code work?

Comment: What `load_func` function does? can you post that code so it can be understood better?

Comment: there is no question here :-) you just want to change sintax of php? :-) there are many others, try python, prolog perl :-) but if you use php - you already know the answer - here is your loop. you can pass you array or maxnumber of elements as second parameter to your function and loop it inside the function. these 2 options is absolutely enough :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass the whole item to load_function();

```
echo load_func($hid, $item);
```

And deal with every item in the function itself.

```
function load_func($hid, $item) {
    $return = "<select id='drpopitem-' name='drpopitem[]' size='10' multiple>";
    foreach ($item as $option) $return .= $option;
    $return .= "</select>";
    return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I am understanding from your question, you should pass the array `$addctr` to the function. And inside the function you should put your `for` loop and do the calculations.

something like:

```
function load_func($id, $items) {
   $strOptions = "";
   for($a=1;$a<=$items;$a++){
       if($items[$a-1] != $id)
          $strOptions .= "<option>Your value</option>";
       else
          $strOptions .= "<option selected>Your value</option>";
   }
   return $strOptions;
}
```